# WebOS 3.0 Enyo Button Onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, webos

i think its an easy question but i am stuck ...

now i am developing for PalmPAD with WebOS 3.0
and i want to design login system in that.

now i want to know if user click on (in login.js page) Register Button on click event i need to open my register.js page

in doc i found this code

Code:

```
enyo.kind({
  name: "MyApps.Sample",
  kind: "enyo.VFlexBox",
  style: "width: 400px; padding: 5px",
  components: [
      {kind: "CustomButton", caption: "unstyled (CustomButton)",
          onclick: "buttonClick"},
      {kind: "Button", caption: "styled (Button)", onclick: "buttonClick"}
  ],
  buttonClick: function() {
      // respond to click
  }
});
```

in this buttonClick: function() what should i write to navigate to the register.js page?

Comment: Enyo is still under NDA, this question should be asked on the developer forums.

Comment: If something is under NDA, it means that the *person that is asking* is technically in breach of their NDA by posting it here. It means nothing for Stack Overflow. Nobody on the SO team, or any of the moderators, have signed an NDA agreement. There is no way SO (as in the site, owners, company, moderators, members) can be aware of all the possible NDA agreements out there, when they are in effect, for whom, when, where, and why, so there is no point in trying to uphold these. If @Ajay wants to risk his membership by posting the question, he's welcome to it.

Comment: @Lasse ok will now never ask any question which tecnologies under NDA.

Comment: The NDA for webOS 3.0 has now been lifted. Ask away.

Comment: Yep !! now is lifted.... any one can ask anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this code:

buttonClick: function() { 
    enyo.create({kind: "register"}).renderInto(document.body); 
  } 
"register" kind is name of the kind of created in register.js file

ex: register.js
enyo.kind({ 
  name: "register", 
  kind: "enyo.VFlexBox", 
  style: "width: 400px; padding: 5px", 
  components: [ 
//add the components whatever you want 
      ],

});

Thanks